# prove that if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ exists, then so does $\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

1. Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and let $ c \in \mathbb{R}$ . Using the definition of integrability
   or the inf-sup criterion prove that if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ exists, then so does $\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)dx$ and these two integrals are equal.

I know what I have to use to prove this problem, but I am not sure how to apply it. Could someone help me get started?

Comment: Can't you simply make the substitution $x -> x + c$ to prove this?

Comment: yes, but it does not state that the function is continuous.. @Vik78

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Riemann sums for both integrals are same. Nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Show that the difference between upper and lower Darboux sums can be made arbitrarily small.

There is a one-to-one mapping of partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$ onto partitions $P'$ of $[a+c,b+c].$

For any subinterval $I$ of $P$ and the corresponding subinterval $I'$ of $P'$ we have

$$\sup_{x \in I}f(x)  = \sup_{x \in I'} f(x-c) \\ \inf_{x \in I}f(x)  = \inf_{x \in I'} f(x-c)$$